# Apache Archiva not caching?

Tags: maven, archiva

I've just set up Archiva and I'm testing it. I'm trying to get `mysql-connector-java` and I'm expecting it to not find it in the internal repository, download it from the central repository and then cache it.

When I check `<archiva>/data/repositories/internal`, however, it's empty. Also *Browse* in the admin pages is empty and *Search* won't return anything.

I'm assuming this means that it's not storing the artifact and that it will get it from the central repo again next time. I'm also assuming I'm not getting something so some help would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My bad - I was using the wrong URL for the repository. I had `http://myrepo:8080/archiva` and it needed `http://myrepo:8080/archiva/repository/internal` so it was going to central repo directly. Works fine now.